# WPF/C#: Disable Drag & Drop for TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, drag-and-drop

Does anyone have an idea how I can disable Drag & Drop for all my TextBox Elements?
I found something [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-disabling-dragging-from-a-textbox), but that would need me to run a loop for all Elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily wrap what this article describes into a attached property/behaviours...

ie. TextBoxManager.AllowDrag="False" (For more information check out these 2 CodeProject articles - [Drag and Drop Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDragDrop.aspx) and Glass Effect Sample[link text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFGlass.aspx))

Or try out the new Blend SDK's Behaviors

**UPDATE**

- Also read [this](http://wekempf.spaces.live.com/feed.rss) article by Bill Kempf about attached behaviors
- And as kek444 pointed out in the comments, you then just create a default style for textbxo whit this attached property set!

Comment: And of course, set the attached properties in a default style for the TextBox, if that is required to save some handwork.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following after InitializeComponent()

```
DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(textboxName, (sender, e) => { if (e.IsDragDrop) e.CancelCommand(); });
```

Comment: For anyone looking to do this, this is by far the simplest way to do it from code. A full explanation is here: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-disabling-dragging-from-a-textbox

Comment: @stone This link is now dead.

Comment: Wayback Machine link for the above dead link: http://web.archive.org/web/20121214030005/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-disabling-dragging-from-a-textbox

Answer (score 2):

Personally I created a custom TextBox control that does not allow drag as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a <see cref="TextBox"/> control that does not allow drag on its contents.
/// </summary>
public class NoDragTextBox:TextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NoDragTextBox"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public NoDragTextBox()
    {
        DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(this, NoDragCopyingHandler);
    }

    private void NoDragCopyingHandler(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsDragDrop)
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using TextBox use local:NoDragTextBox where "local" being the alias to the location of the NoDragTextBox assembly. The same above logic also can be extended to prevent Copy/Paste on TextBox .

For more info check the reference to the above code at http://jigneshon.blogspot.be/2013/10/c-wpf-snippet-disabling-dragging-from.html

Answer (score 1):

Create your owner user control ex MyTextBox: TextBox and override:

```
    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }


    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It prevents drop, but not drag from the control. Furthermore, horrible things may happen when you drop the text from the textbox somewhere else.

Comment: @Mark, example of horrible things?

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could remember.