# How to disable drag and drop in a wpf data grid view column

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, datagridviewcolumn

In my application, I have Data grid view which contains 10 columns, DataGridTemplateColumn type. I want to disable moving last column in the data grid view.Which means It cannot be dragged into other columns or dropped to other columns. How can I achieve this? I have tried solutions in below link.

> [1]:
>   [WPF/C#: Disable Drag & Drop for TextBoxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130949/wpf-c-disable-drag-drop-for-textboxes)

But None of the solutions worked for me since they have tried the solutions for textbox control which is a UI Element. So when I try those solutions it throws below mentioned error.

> "System.ArgumentException 
>   Message='System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn' is not a
>   valid type for IInputElement. UIElement or ContentElement expected."

Any guidance or solution on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF/C#: Disable Drag & Drop for TextBoxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130949/wpf-c-disable-drag-drop-for-textboxes)

Comment: @Jawad No, The problem is I have DataGrid, which contains DataGridTemplateColumn's. But in the above mentioned answer, answer is applicable for Textboxes. Since Textboxes are UI Element when I apply those solutions it throws this error. "System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message='System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn' is not a valid type for IInputElement. UIElement or ContentElement expected."

Comment: Do you want to disable the dragging of the column header or an element in the cell?

Comment: @samarsinghe0804: And what does "the whole column" mean?

Comment: @mm8 I want to disable the dragging of column header